# Add one text with one variable number to multiple files using bash

Tags: bash

I want to create a script that put a text (with many lines) as a header in multiple files with txt extension. But the text to be inserted need to put filename of the file in which it will be inserted.

## text(to be inserted)

abcdgd FILENAME dhsgabc
shcnwk shfgamvk
cjshjg  nwdcbi
skfh nwvjcnd

## skfh dvwuv

I have many files, with the name 001.txt, 002.txt, 003.txt and so on ... 
SO the NAMEFILE need to be only 001 , 002 , 003 , and so on .. (without the .txt extension)

thanks

Comment: cooooooooooooooooooool

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I have no idea what to do? I am a beginner

Comment: also asked on http://askubuntu.com/q/723797/10127 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256772/4667

Comment: Awesome, @AlvaroLopez is pasting my answer (from unix SE) and saying that this is what HE have done so far... I'm getting so upset with this guy...

Answer (score 0):

This script will create a new set of files named 001.txt.new, 002.txt.new,... with the changes you requested:

```
# Create a re-usable header file:
cat > header << @@
abcdgd FILENAME dhsgabc shcnwk shfgamvk cjshjg nwdcbi skfh nwvjcnd
@@

# Loop over all files:
for i in [0-9][0-9][0-9].txt; do
  # Get file name without suffix:
  NAME=$(echo $i|sed -r 's/(.*)\.txt/\1/'

  # Create a new file containing the modified header line:
  cat header | sed 's/FILENAME/'"$NAME"'/' > ${i}.out

  # Append contents of the original file to the new file:
  cat $i >> ${i}.out
done
```

If you want to completely replace the original files you can add this line to the end of loop:

```
mv ${i}.out $i
```

But you'd probably want to back-up your original files in some way before replacing them.